# UISplitController: How can I place detail sub-view in front of root view?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uikit, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm writing an iPad application and I need a bar to span the entire bottom of the screen, in front of both the root controller's view and the detail controller's view. The bar is a sub-view of the detail controller's view, and I have "clip sub-views" turned off so that it extends outwards to the left of the detail controller's view's bounds. However, it ends up behind the root view controller's view. How can I bring it in front of the root view?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling -bringSubviewToFront: like so?

[myRootView bringSubviewToFront:myBarView];

Comment: The problem is that the view I want to place in front of the root view is not a subview of the root view - it's a subview of the detail view.

Comment: It sounds like it should be a subview of the root view, then.  You could add a method to your detail view controller that could be called by the root view controller that returns the view you want to have shown over the root view, and have the root view controller make it a subview of the root view rather than try to make it a subview of the detail view.  That way the detail view controller gets to decide what view will be displayed, but the view hierarchy makes sense.

Comment: I thought it made more sense for it to be a subview of the detail view, since when the device is in landscape mode, the detail view will still be on the screen, and the bar will still be on top of it (the root view will be hidden unless the user explicitly requests it). That being said, I'm happy to try and model it your way.

Comment: That's understandable, but I assume that in both cases the root view is still the root view in the hierarchy, so it needs to be the parent of both views in order to achieve the desired effect without bending over backwards.